# Magento loadByAttribute name - error with german umlaut chars

Tags: magento

In a custom import module, I want to load the category by name like this:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('name', $categoryName)
```

but I get a Fatal error when there is an deutsch special char.

How can I fix this Problem.

Note: I get the category names from a "ISO-8859-1" csv file.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Magento database is utf8 by default. Probably you should convert your data to utf8 using iconv or mbstring.

Comment: @Zyava: The error is : "PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object..."; I have tried with : `iconv("ISO-8859-1","UTF-8",trim($categoryName))` but that don't help.

Comment: Could you post whole piece of code? Because I don't see where `getId()` method is called here.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, my problem was that some catgories was not already created. Problem solved.

Thanks a lot.